# Mod Rewrite - Regular Expression to include everything but slash

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess I have a rewrite rule which reads `$_GET` values from a clean looking url. For one of the sections in the url I'm allowing all characters `(.*)` to be part of the var. The only issue with this is when I follow a link to my site from twitter, it includes a final '/ ' in the url.

```
RewriteRule ^advertise/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ advertise/?a=b&content=$1&content_att=$2 [L]
```

`www.mysite.com/advertise/content/content_att` works just fine 
- but
`www.mysite.com/advertise/content/content_att/` trys including the '/ ' as part of the `content_att` var. What would the expression be to only exclude slashes? (or any other mod_rewrite convention to accomplish this)

Comment: Edited - those are slashes `/` not backslashes \

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[^/]` will include any character except `/`
`[^/]*` will include any number of characters that are not `/`

In action should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^advertise/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ advertise/?a=b&content=$1&content_att=$2 [L]
```

Comment: You are right. should be `+`. I see you have basically the same answer, except it was before mine. So, update your answer with the whole rewrite rule and I will delete mine.